# logwatch "pam_unix" section vs "sshd section"

Tags: security, authentication, ssh

As you may know Logwatch is a tool that will monitor your server's logs and email the administrator a digest on a daily basis.

I have received this in my daily Logwatch report.

```
=================================================
- pam_unix
-- sshd:
--- Session Opened: 
     userA: 2 Time(s) 
     userB: 1 Time(s)

- SSHD
--Users logging in through sshd:
     userA: x.x.x.x 2 Time(s)
=================================================
```

Well, I do not know what is the difference between this two `sshd` sections?
And what is the difference between the two users I can get from this report?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. THis question is more suitable for [Serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/)
2. users in `ssh` connections are authenticated using PAM (using password) and it results in two messages in log. If you authenticate using public key, you don't see the PAM event, if I am right.

Comment: thanks for your help I gues your answer is what I was searching for ( I'm new here .. and didn't paid enough attention to the "topics" )..